# I'm getting an error and im not sure why?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

This is the part of code that is having the error.

```
#include "MyForm.h"
; using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void main(array<String^>^ args)
{
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

V_Hello_World::MyForm form;
Application::Run(%form);
}
```

The error is: Error 1   error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{'. I'm not sure why this error is occurring but some help would be very much appreciated.

***MyForm.h***

```
#pragma once

namespace V_Hello_World {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

    protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected:

    protected:

    private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Minion  Pro", 14.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold,   System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(260, 237);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"Say Hello";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
        // 
        // MyForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"MyForm";
        this->Text = L"MyForm";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Hello World!");
    }
};
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
}
```

Comment: The problem could be in `"MyForm.h"`

Comment: This is C++/CLI and WinForms, not C++.

Comment: Can you add the contents of `"MyForm.h"` to your question?

Comment: I have added MyForm.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start running issue at

```
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Hello World!");
    }
};
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
}
```

Your first issue is you have two open curly braces for `button1_Click` but only one close brace.  You should just be able to remove one of the open curly braces.  Your second issue is `MyForm_Load` is outside the class body.  You need to move it into the class declaration.

Comment: I have tried to remove both of the brackets, not at the same time, and when I do that it starts underlining a bunch of other stuff in red saying that its wrong.

Comment: @Punny Did you get it?  I see you placed the accept mark on the answer.

Comment: For the most part yes I suppose, but the original error popped up again and I figured I'd leave y'all be and keep trying to figure it out. Sorry if I wasted any of your time. ;/